# Comparing a String value to ALL values in an Enum in C# using TryParse - Logic Issue

Tags: c#, string, enums, tryparse

I'm trying to determine if a string value read-in from a file is found within an enum in my code.

**The enum:**

```
internal enum Difficulty { None, Easy, Medium, Hard }
```

At this point in my code `header[i] = "EASY"`.
I want to compare this value to any of the values found in my `Difficulty` enum but am encountering issues.

**The code:**

Each time the following code is executed, the if statement returns false because `"Easy" != "EASY"`.

```
Difficulty dif = Difficulty.None;
if (Difficulty.TryParse(header[i], out dif)) {      // RETURNS FALSE
    MyLog.Write("It's in the Enum!");
}
```

I've tried comparing the `header[i]` value to the `Difficulty` value in the `TryParse` statement, but it results in a compiler error.

Is there anything I can do besides changing all the `Difficulty` values to uppercase ones?

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question in the question itself. If you have found a solution, either mark one of the answers as correct or add an answer yourself.

Comment: @progy_rock My apologies, I had forgotten. I merely added the solution to my question for easy accessibility for anyone that reads this later on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.ToString` value for any `Enum` returns just the name your provide for it. So if you're gonna be doing this in a loop i suggest getting all the names to a local list and search in that which would result in better performance:

```
string[] enumNames = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Difficulty));

bool found = enumNames.Any(x => x.Equals(header[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the version of TryParse that supports ignoring case: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991317(v=vs.110).aspx

Your code becomes:

```
Difficulty dif = Difficulty.None;
if (Enum.TryParse<Difficulty>(header[i], true, out dif))
{      
    MyLog.Write("It's in the Enum!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is!

Use [the overload for Enum.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991317(v=vs.110).aspx) that allows you to ignore the case:

```
if (Enum.TryParse("EASY", true, out dif))
{      
    Console.WriteLine("It's in the Enum!");
}
```